# Windows 7 / Auto Login - Is it possible to delay auto-login for 15-30 seconds?

Tags: windows-7, auto-login

Is it possible to have an auto login delay for Windows 7? The user folder for my primary account is stored on a separate drive. In case of drive failure, or some other problem - I need to login as Admin (stored on C:).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible.

Whilst it may be possible to insert some sort of process that delays the login screen from being shown, the moment that the login screen is shown, it will automatically log in.

All this being said, in the event of a drive failure, as long as the default profile is not located on the other drive, you should still be able to login with the default profile.

I am not aware of what happens if the default profile fails to load, however, I assume it will go back to the log in screen.

In addition, you can always launch safe mode as this will always show the login screen, even with auto login enabled.